# How can I get all possible characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Suppose all the characters in JavaScript were `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`. What I'm trying to do is create a random mapping between characters. So the above might be like

```
{ `a` : `e`,
  `b` : `b`, 
  `c` : `e`, 
  `d` : `b`,
  `e` : `a`,
  `f` : `c` }
```

First, how can I get all the possible characters in JavaScript?

```
var AllChars = new Array(); 
// ... fill AllChars with the full range of characters
```

Comment: Have you considered Unicode characters as well?

Comment: Do you mean special characters or only letters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: *get all the possible characters* Do you even know how many there are in Unicode?

Comment: Why do you need it for all characters?

Comment: Normally, when you want a random mapping between characters, you don't actually put all characters in a map.  You make a pseudo-random function that takes a character as an argument and returns the character it maps to.  This is a simple form of encryption.

Comment: @MattTimmermans You mean a hashing function

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  kinda like a hashing function, but bijective.  A pseudo-random permutation of characters instead of a general pseudo-random function.  You can make these out of hash functions using the Fiestel structure, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example on how to generate an array with all the lowercase letters:

```
var AllChars = [];
for (var i=97; i<123; i++)
    AllChars.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
```

> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
>   "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

**Edit** to include all ascii printable characters per Aaron recommendation:

```
var AllChars = [];
for (var i=32; i<127; i++)
  AllChars.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
```

> [" ", "!", """, "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-",
>   ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";",
>   "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
>   "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
>   "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e",
>   "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
>   "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~"]

Comment: You could also add to your answer to retrieve all ascii printable characters. They're the 32-126 range.

Comment: Done :) I've also changed the index access by `push` when populating the array to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner for all lowercase chars:

```
Array(26)
    .fill(97)
    .map((x, y) => String.fromCharCode(x + y))
```